# What is the correct Way to integrate KSOAP library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am trying something like this,

In Gradle,

Inside Build Types,

```
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://ksoap2-android.googleco/svde.cmomn/2-repo'
  }
```

and in dependencies . . .

```
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
```

> Error: Failed to resolve dependencies

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Solution: inside `build.gradle` of a module (not project) write:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
```

and inside Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2'
```

Comment: It works like a charm, but what is the difference between this method and add it as Library?

Comment: This doesn't work today. Is there any best alternative?

Comment: It works. But version updated. Latest ksoap2 version is 3.6.4. Try change the version number. Work for me.

Answer (score 3):

in Android Studio, you have two build.gradle File:

My first file (Project):

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my Second File (Module):

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asemansystem.com.caferc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `repositories { }` branch in module's `build.gradle` helped. But in an accepted answer `mavenCentral()` is unneeded, so you can also remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Goto to this [link](https://javalibs.com/artifact/com.google.code.ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android) and download the jar file. Then add the downloaded jar file to your libs folder inside your app folder(**Your Project->app->libs**).
Then right click on the ksoap jar file and select "**Add as Library**".

Done.

**EDIT : UPDATED THE LINK**

Comment: Then right click on the ksoap jar file and select "Add as Library". where this option resides ?

Comment: i have updated the link. Go to  the link, scroll down, click on the version you want. Then download.

Answer (score 0):

this is mine in new versions of Android Studio:

in **build.gradle** (module):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.4'
}
```

in **settings.gradle**:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "idt.pda"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is:

1: **Download** the `ksoap2-versionX.jar` file from [here](http://ask.android-studio.org/?/file/download/file_name-a3NvYXAyLTMuNF8uMF8uemlw__url-aHR0cDovL2Fzay5hbmRyb2lkLXN0dWRpby5vcmcvdXBsb2Fkcy9hbnN3ZXIvMjAxNTAxMjUvOWQzZjU1YWEzYzE2Y2Q1NzIxNDcxZGIyYjg1ZDkwYWE=).

2: **Copy** `ksoap2-versionX.jar` file to **libs** folder in your project.

3: Right click in the copied file in your project and select **Add as library**.

See:
http://ask.android-studio.org/?/question/188